how to remove or get only the name 3000 times in the google sheet using the formula (=ARRAYFORMULA("Badchana"&sequence(3000))
i want a name to repeated 3000 times instead of dragging it for 3000 rows so I used
=ARRAYFORMULA("Badchana"&sequence(3000))

but i am getting it as name1,name2.......name3000
kindly suggest a formula where the number will be removed and only the name will be visible for 3000 rows.

try: =TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(1,3000),"Badchana"))

Use if(), like this:
=arrayformula(if(sequence(3000), "Badchana"))

Any non-zero number is considered true by if(). See if().

Another solution:
=LET(_,"Badchana",WRAPCOLS(_,3000,_))

